# Is this true :if $x\in [0.2] $ then $f(x)=\frac{2x+3}{x+2} \in [0.2]$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, supremum-and-infimum

I'm sorry to ask this question mayeb it's a trivial question but i would like to confirme if i have this function $f(x)=\frac{2x+3}{x+2}$ which  $x$ is a real number in $[0.2] $ then $f(x) \in [0.2]$ ?

**My question here is** :

Is this true :if $x\in [0.2] $ then $f(x) \in [0.2]$ and  why is not in $]0.2]$  ?

**Note** : The function is increasing and no values in the above area satisfy $f(x)=0$

Comment: **Hint:**$$\frac{2x+3}{x+2}=\frac{2x+4-1}{x+2}=2-\frac1{x+2}$$

Comment: yes i did this but my problem why is not in (0.2] ?

Comment: The identity holds for all $x\neq -2$, hence there is no problem for $x=0$.

Comment: I meant $f(x)$ never be $0 $ for $x \in  [0.2]$

Comment: yes exactly  , then f(x) can't be 0

Comment: You only need to show that if $0\leq x\leq 2$ then $$0\leq f(x)\leq 2$$ but it's not needed that $f(x)=0$ for some $x\in [0,2]$

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=\frac{2x+3}{x+2}=2-\frac{1}{x+2}$ is increasing on $[0,2]$, hence $f(x)\geq f(0)=\frac{3}{2}$ and $f(x)\leq f(2)=\frac{7}{4}$ for $x\in [0,2]$.

Comment: The function is strict increasing !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\frac{2x+3}{x+2}=\frac{(x+2)+(x+1)}{x+2}=1+\frac{x+1}{x+2}$$

Answer (score 0):

You only need to show that if $0\leq x\leq 2$ then $$0\leq f(x)\leq 2$$ but it's not needed that $f(x)=0$ for some $x\in [0,2]$.

Since $$f(x)=\frac{2x+3}{x+2}=\frac{2x+4-1}{x+2}=2-\frac{1}{x+2}\qquad\qquad\text{for all }x\neq -2$$
It follows that $$0\leq x\leq 2\quad\implies \quad2\leq x+2\leq 4\quad\implies\quad \frac14\leq \frac1{x+2}\leq\frac12$$
Then $$2-\frac12\leq2-\frac1{x+2}\leq2-\frac14\qquad\implies\qquad \frac32\leq f(x)\leq\frac74\quad \forall x\in[0,2]$$

Since $[\frac32,\frac74]$ is a subset of $[0,2]$ the result follows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer however i showed that is with same method  but could u show me a little bit why is not needed f(x)=0 for some x in [0.2]  My guess is if  0=<x <=2 then f(x) must be in (0.2) since no x in this interval satisfy for example f(x)=0 or f(x)=2 ?

Comment: I can say you my age is a number between $0$ and $100$ but surely it is not needed that my age must be $0$ or $100$.

Comment: since I know that f(x)=2 when x go to infty and no x in [0.2] satisfy f(x)=0 why i do a probability for f(x) to be 0 or to be 2 ?